# When I Link Some Modifiers From One Object To Another It Dosen't Copy All of Them

Tags: modifiers, physics

I have two physics modifiers. One is a *Soft Body* the second one is a *Collision*. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and link the modifiers it doesn't copy the *Collision* and if the *Collision* modifier is already there it will be taken off. 
This could also just be a 2.81 bug.

To recreate, make a cube, then go to *Physics*. Add *Collision* and *Soft Body* to one and make another cube add *Collision* to it. 
Then select the one with *Collision* first then then select the other one hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select *Modifiers*.

Comment: I presume you mean Ctrl+L?

Comment: Yes I mean't ctrl L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported to the bug tracker, here: [T66798](https://developer.blender.org/T66798)

It was concluded that it was intentional that it works this way and was therefore not a bug.

Philipp Oeser had this to say:

> - from the Physics panel, Forcefield, Ridgid Body, Ridgid Body Constraint are no real modifiers, so these wont be copied
> - Collision is explicitly excluded in code [this could be made working, needs some care because data related to collisions is stored
>     in PartDeflect which has other stuff in it too, cant just copy it,
>     will look into it but that's for later...]
> - the others seem to be working fine
> - so no bug here

Essentially, this seems to be saying that the *Collision* modifier is skipped because there is other data that can't be copied in a simple way. So, rather than a bug, it seems to be a limitation which may or may not be improved in the future.

As to why any *existing* modifiers are removed from the object you want to copy modifiers to, existing modifiers are *replaced*, not *added to*. So any existing modifiers are removed before any modifiers that can be copied are added.

Comment: Okay then since I had applied the collision modifier before linking it should of stayed on in stead pf getting removed from the physics tab.

Comment: When you do Ctrl+L all modifiers on the selected objects are *replaced* not *added to*. So all existing modifiers are removed then modifiers that can be copied over are added.